# Node version differs between npm scripts and command line

Tags: node.js

Given this script in `package.json`:

```js
"v": "node -v"
```

On the Windows git-bash command line:

```sh
$ npm run v

> mymod@1.0.0 v
> node -v

v10.23.0

$ node -v
v14.16.0
```

As far as I know, I have only Node 14 on my system.

What have I missed that could be causing this?